# Unable to fetch data from firebase using cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase using cloud functions but every time i get **null** in return. However I came to know that i am able to get data but after execution of function is completed. (console.log() is printing the values after function finishes)

```
exports.getChatRecord = functions.https.onRequest(async(request, response) => {

const uid:string = request.body.uid


if (uid === undefined){
    return response.send("1313")
}

const ref = admin.database().ref('user_chat_record').child(uid)
var ref1 

try {

const allMessages = new Array()

await ref.once('value', async function(snapShot:DataSnapshot){
await snapShot.forEach(function(snap:DataSnapshot){

    const match_uid = snap.key
    let chat_key:string
    if (match_uid.localeCompare(uid) < 0){
        chat_key = match_uid+uid; // keep match uid in front
        }
    else chat_key = uid+match_uid;  
    console.log(chat_key)

    ref1 = admin.database().ref('chats').child(chat_key)

     ref1.once('value', async function(shot:DataSnapshot){
         console.log(shot.val()) // it prints data but after function execution finishes
         await allMessages.push(shot.val()) // here not able to get data
        })

    return false
 })  
})

 return response.json(allMessages)

}
catch (err){
    return response.send("error "+err)
}

});
```

Comment: Your code looks incorrect to me.  You are mixing up async/await with database callbacks.  If you're using async/await with the promise returned by `once()`, you shouldn't also be using its callback.

Comment: @DougSteveson I'm new to cloud functions so I don't have deep understanding of the concept. It will be very helpful if you can pin point the mistake in my code or you can refer me good tutorial or docs for the same.

Comment: The issue isn't so much with learning Cloud Functions as it is understanding how promises work.  Proper handling of promises is foundational to writing correct JavaScript.  Check this video series for more information.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Also I would recommand writing something simple first, then increase its complexity over time as you are confident it's working the way you expect.  You have a lot of code here to debug, and it's easier to debug if you trim it down.